# Code in VBA to skip cells based on background color

Tags: excel, vba

I must create a scheduling code that will generate the steps to its respective day. This process is 6 steps and each step takes a day, however it cannot be done on weekends which I have colored coated grey. Is there a way to code in VBA to say that if the process starts Wednesday, it will generate Steps 6-4 for Wed-Fri and then resume the rest of the process on Monday for steps 3-1?
Below is the code I have created to generate the steps into its respective box.
I appreciate the help!

```
Sub Process()

Dim c As Range

If Selection.Value = "Step 6" Then
Selection.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Step 5"
Selection.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Step 4"
Selection.Offset(0, 3).Value = "Step 3"
Selection.Offset(0, 4).Value = "Step 2"
Selection.Offset(0, 5).Value = "Step 1"
Selection.Offset(0, 6).Value = "Finish"

End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Generally, such things are very basically handled as follows: `for (element in Collection) { if condition(element) then action(element)}`.

Comment: Check the `Range.Interior.Color` property to see the color value of the background. Create an If Expression to handle the case where it is grey.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the input! I was able to create and test a code myself based on the weekends gray color

```
ActiveCell.Value = "Step 1"
If Selection.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 15 Then
Selection.Offset(0, 4).Value = "Step 2"
Selection.Offset(0, 5).Value = "Step 3"
ElseIf Selection.Offset(0, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 15 Then
Selection.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Step 2"
Selection.Offset(0, 5).Value = "Step 3"
ElseIf Selection.Offset(0, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 15 Then
Selection.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Step 2"
Selection.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Step 3"

End If

End Sub
```